# I get syntaxERROR invalid syntax with my code

Tags: python, syntax

this is my python program and whenever i try to run it i get that error at line 3 where weight_kg is, i've just started learning this language today so i'm not sure what's the problem

```
name="Kenza"
height_m=float(input("enter the height:")
weight_kg=input("enter the weight :")
bmi=weight_kg/(height**2)
print("bmi is:")
print(bmi)
if  bmi>=25 :
    print(name)
    print("is overweight")
else:
if bmi <25 and bmi > 18.5:
    print(name)
    print("is normal weight")
else:
    if bmi<18.5:
        print(name)
        print("she is underweight")
```

Comment: The answer to this is always the same: you have a missing `)` on the line before.

Comment: Every `(` needs a matching `)`. There are two `(` but only one `)`. If you use a good IDE (such as PyCharm or Visual Studio Code) it will automatically add the `)` whenever you type `(`.

Comment: thank you! i added it and i still get some other error that says: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hp/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    bmi=weight/float(height_m**2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'

Comment: `weight_kg` is a string because you didn't call `float()` like you did for `height_m`.

Comment: You need to convert both inputs to `float` if you want to use them in arithmetic.

Comment: Another problem: You assign `height_m` but then try to use `height` in the calculation.

Comment: Your `else: if` should be `elif:`

Comment: thank you so much!! it worked now ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`height_m=float(input("enter the height:")`

you need to add an extra bracket at the end of this line